# Printing number in an array backwards

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java and I wondering how I could fix my program which has to take numbers from user input, then store them in an array, and then print those numbers forwards and then backwards. I have managed to get the program to print forward; however, when I try to print it backwards I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
>   at arrays4Days.arrayS1.main(arrayS1.java:55)

```
import java.util.*;
public class arrayS1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many numbers will you enter? ");
        int count = console.nextInt();
        int myArray[]= new int [count];

        for (int i =0; i < myArray.length ; i++) {
            System.out.print("Type a number: ");
            int number=console.nextInt();
            myArray[i]=number;
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your numbers in forward order:");

        for (int i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your numbers in backward order:");

        for (int i = myArray.length ; i> 0  ; i--) {
            System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `int i = myArray.length`: can you explain why you think that the length of an array also yields a valid index? If this would be the case, then why have you written `i < myArray.length` instead of `i < myArray.length` in the first loop?

Comment: I thought that myarray.length represents the amount of values that are stored in the array. I used that to set the max amount of times the for loop could loop (for my first loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in your first loop, `i` starts at zero and goes up to - but not equals - the length of the array

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++) {
```

so the second loop should also start at this position

```
for (int i = myArray.length - 1; i>= 0  ; i--) {
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

and should go down to zero